# How to compare and get the difference of two path strings

Tags: node.js

I have two file path as strings:

```
const filePath = "reports/cucumber/7/cucumber/sample/json/login.json"
const reportFolder = "reports/cucumber/7/cucumber/sample"
```

I need to compare these two and then get the output as

```
/json/login.json
```

How can I do this?

Comment: can you add more detail what you need? what output you need? conflict output or merge output?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `String.replace()` to get the difference:

```js
const filePath = "reports/cucumber/7/cucumber/sample/json/login.json"
const reportFolder = "reports/cucumber/7/cucumber/sample"

const diff = filePath.replace(reportFolder, '');
console.log('Diff:', diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filePath = "reports/cucumber/7/cucumber/sample/json/login.json"
const reportFolder = "reports/cucumber/7/cucumber/sample"

const diff = (diffMe, diffBy) => diffMe.split(diffBy).join('')

const C = diff(filePath, reportFolder)

console.log(C)
```